# ResourceString file equivalent on iOS

Tags: ios, resources

So here is the whole story.
I have done alot of code for a lot of platforms. 
I really like the concept that I have found in Java and .NET with a resource file that can contain all the strings you will use in your app. Hopefully some of you know about it. It's basically an XML file sorted in a key=>value kind of way.
I have been looking for an equivalent in iOS but I'm unclear. There is infoPlist.strings, but that seems like the wrong path. I may be wrong.

So what we want is, we have a whole bunch of strings that get repeated in multiple places (alert boxes, direction text, etc.). We need that to be a change once kind of experience. There are multiple ways of doing this, I just don't know which one is the best.

I'm not really eloquent, so if anyone has questions or needs clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If localization is not what you are trying to do, then you could just put them in a dictionary in a plist file. Have your app read the plist file at app startup and store in a global variable or some singleton that can be easily referenced throughout your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by the localization system. Look at `NSLocalizedString()` and [Localizing String Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html). It should do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it and get back to you. This looks like the right path.

Comment: Well, here is my concern. This is for localization, and the system seems goofy for what we are trying to do. Here is an example of the exact problem. Client wants to change the text of ALL the "submit" buttons (anything that kicks off a web service) from "Submit" to "OK". They are talking about changing to "Apply" or "Continue". There are 15 buttons. Don't want to be going through and finding all these and changing the titles. We want to just change the string once and be done with it. We also want the code to support this kind of change.

Comment: Correct. This is exactly what NSLocalizedString() allows by changing the `.strings` file. You'd have the line `"SUBMIT_BUTTON_CAPTION" = "Submit";` in `Localizeable.strings`, and you'd change it to `"SUBMIT_BUTTON_CAPTION" = "OK";`. (Or however you like to name your keys.) Isn't that what you described? You'd then be set-up if you ever wanted to translate into other languages, but you don't have to do that.